# Pathria's "Statistical Mechanics" first edition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, soft-question, specific-reference

Does anyone know where I could find and purchase the book "Statistical Mechanics" by R. Pathria, in 1st edition (the 2nd and the 3rd are readily available, but I really need the first). I believe the first edition was published in 1972. I have searched high and low for it, but can't seem to find it even on Amazon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to purchase a book.  There is no physics concept here and although the question used the [tag:specific-reference] tag, this question isn't about finding an unknown but specific reference; it's about purchasing a known specific reference.

Comment: Any particular reason you're after the first edition? If it's to look at some specific part which has disappeared/been changed in later editions, then you might also simply try to find it online. It's very easy.

Comment: @YvanVelenik: Do you mean it's very easy to find the book online?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. There are some well-known sites specialized in scanned copies of scientific books. I don't want to encourage piracy, of course, but it is sometimes very convenient when you want to have a quick look at the content and are too lazy to go to the library ;) (plus, you have the benefit of being able to electronically search through the text, which can be convenient if you're only looking for a particular statement that you expect might be in the book). I won't put a link here, but if you need one, write to me directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that for older books, you want to check out Alibris.com, rather than Amazon. So a quick search there turned up a [few copies of the 1972 edition](http://www.alibris.com/search/books/isbn/9780080189949?qwork=6325216qsort=dr#search-anchor).